# Display total price in HTML template

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have a cart app. When I add products I want to find total price. But I cannot display in my template. But I display in console it shows true value.

**solved** *And I have a delete button when I click this I want to give alert with "Are you sure?" but it doesn't work. How can I fix it?* **solved**

**views.py**

```
def cart_view(request):
    current_user = request.user
    carts = MedicineOnCart.objects.filter(cart__user=current_user)
    cart = Cart.objects.get(user=current_user)

    dictionary = {}
    for cart in carts:
        if cart.med in dictionary.keys():
            dictionary[cart.med] += 1
        else:
            dictionary[cart.med] = 1

    new_total = 0.00

    for item in MedicineOnCart.objects.all():
        new_total += item.med.medicine_price

    cart.total = new_total
    cart.save()

    context = {
                "carts": dictionary,
                "user": current_user,
               }
    template = "cart.html"

    return render(request, template, context)
```

**template.html**

```
     <td>
         Total: {{carts.total}}
     </td>
                <button class="btn btn-danger myButton" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" > Delete  </button>
```

Comment: `onclick="deleteMess()"`. Altough the answer to that `alert()` will not affect the coming process. You should use `return confirm("Are you sure?");"` and `onclick="return deleteMess()"` or just `onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"`. However not that adding js inline is not good practise.

Answer (score 0):

You save the total amount of the cart in the last instance of `cart` but in your template the variable `carts` contais a the `dictionary` variable, is better you replace `cart.total = new_total` to `dictionary['total'] = new_total`

Comment: When I do this, it prints somewhere that I don't want.because I have         <td> {{value}} </td>    row